# how to fit 5 buttons besides 4 buttons in python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
class calculate:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.numbers = tk.Frame(master = self.window)
        self.signs = tk.Frame(master = self.window)
        self.lst, self.lst2 = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,".","="),("C","+","-","*","/")
    def buttons(self):
        val = 0
        for i in range(4):
            for j in range(3):
                self.numbutton = tk.Button(master = self.numbers,text = self.lst[val])
                self.numbutton.grid(row = i,column = j)
                val += 1
        for i in range(5):
            self.signbutton = tk.Button(master = self.signs,text = self.lst2[i])
            self.signbutton.grid(row = i)
    def packing(self):
        self.numbers.grid(column= 0,row = 0,rowspan = 4)
        self.signs.grid(column = 1,row = 0,rowspan = 4)
        self.window.mainloop()
    
calculator = calculate()
calculator.buttons()
calculator.packing()
```

I am trying to put some buttons by using gird in python tkinter.
and I want that numbers and signs have same height.
but the signs is of larger height.
please help.
Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can force the size of a frame by giving the frame an height:

```
self.numbers = tk.Frame(master = self.window, height=200)
self.signs = tk.Frame(master = self.window, height=200)
```

Both frames will have a height of 200 but you can change it to whatever you want

Comment: The size will not take effect because there are widgets inside the frames, causing the frames to shrink to fit.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for i in range(4):
            for j in range(3):
                self.numbutton = tk.Button(master = self.numbers,text = self.lst[val],width=5,height=5)
                self.numbutton.grid(row = i,column = j)
                val += 1
        for i in range(5):
            self.signbutton = tk.Button(master = self.signs,text = self.lst2[i],width=5, height=4)
            self.signbutton.grid(row = i)
```

Add a padding in y of some 0.1 or 0.2 to make it look good.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `sticky="nsew"` to all `.grid(...)` and add `self.numbers.rowconfigure("all", weight=1)` to make the number buttons to use all the available space inside `self.numbers` frame.

Below is modified code:

```py
import tkinter as tk

class calculate:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.numbers = tk.Frame(master=self.window)
        self.signs = tk.Frame(master=self.window)
        self.lst, self.lst2 = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,".","="), ("C","+","-","*","/")
    def buttons(self):
        val = 0
        for i in range(4):
            for j in range(3):
                self.numbutton = tk.Button(master=self.numbers, text=self.lst[val])
                self.numbutton.grid(row=i, column=j, sticky="nsew") # added sticky
                val += 1
        for i in range(5):
            self.signbutton = tk.Button(master=self.signs, text=self.lst2[i])
            self.signbutton.grid(row=i, sticky="nsew") # added sticky
    def packing(self):
        self.numbers.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="nsew") # added sticky
        self.signs.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky="nsew") # added sticky
        self.numbers.rowconfigure("all", weight=1) # use all available vertical space
        self.window.mainloop()
    
calculator = calculate()
calculator.buttons()
calculator.packing()
```